# Schneider technical assistance global (not country specific)

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, service

**Background**

I live in Indonesia. The voltage for residential buildings ranges from 220 V to 230 V, I need help with the installation of the following Schneider products with the corresponding links to the threads I posted in diy.stackexchange.com:

[Power Source Box and SPD Box -
Surge Arrester A9L15687 and its dedicated external Short Circuit Protection Device A9K24240](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241592/surge-arrester-surge-protection-device-spd-type-2-installation-and-its-externa)

[MCB Box and Relay Box -
RCCB A9R71240, MCB A9K24220, Contactor A9C20862, Contactor A9C20842 Overvoltage and Undervoltage Relay RM17UBE15, On-delay Relay RE17RAMU](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/243349/on-delay-under-and-overvoltage-relay-contactors-ac-7a-ac-7b-relay-contact)

**Questions**

1. Are there any ways I can reach Schneider technical agents who are able to help with questions from any countries? I have reached out to the ones in my country and they have helped me a lot, however, I still need further clarification of my issues.

I do not mean to say that the agents here do not perform well, in fact, they have been very helpful. As I am dealing with electrical installations, I think it is wise if I want to be 100% sure to avoid any serious incidents.

I am aware that technical agents in one country are equipped with product knowledge of the products offered in that country so agents from another country might not be familiar with the products not offered in their location.

2. Are there any online consultation services with a certified electrician that can help with my issues?

Comment: That will come out and charge you money to do the work? Sure. That will charge you money to do what we do here for free so that it's legit? Hmm. I'm not sure how they could be sure they'd get paid... How does this work for lawyers? Don't you get a 'free consultation' that tells you nothing other than how much it's going to cost *at the very least*? Same with the estimate they'd give you to do the work.

Comment: Debatably, anywhere where you pay one, yes-man, money to do something isn't going to be better than a crowd source. "I want to be 100% sure to avoid any serious incidents." that's why you pulled a permit, are a licensed electrician or otherwise permitted to do the work, and will have your work inspected by the AHJ... right? That's why their job and these rules exist.

Comment: *reach Schneider technical agents from other countries?*  Is there only one phone number and they route your call? Spoof your area code on your phone somehow. Use VoIP. Spoof your own location on your computer when you google them. [When I google them](https://www.se.com/us/en/work/support/customer-care/contact-schneider-electric.jsp) from Chicago I get an 877 number, which is Canada. 1 877 342 5173 M~F 8AM~8PM EST.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because contacting a manufacturer's help line, while a good idea, isn't really DIY or Home Improvement. Finding an alternate help line isn't either.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't just call them back and ask your additional questions? Most help desks have multiple tiers of support - the folks who answer all the questions are tier 1. If they can't answer the question, they bump it up to tier 2 who will look into it further and call you back. Some even have tier 3 which is, basically, the people who actually design the products.

Comment: @Mazura I generally agree with you. However, we've had a bunch of questions from Indonesian residents lately, and it seems that their electrical code and actual, real-world adherence to it are somewhat.. _vague_, especially in comparison to what you might find in the US or EU. It seems to be something of "whatever didn't kill you today is just fine, even if it might kill you in the future". I understand the OP's interest in getting more info in an attempt to do it to US/EU type standards - somewhat above Indonesian ones.

Comment: See [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/241592/surge-arrester-surge-protection-device-spd-type-2-installation-and-its-externa) for more details on the OP's situation.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even touch that one. Anyone doing stuff like, that's not under tutelage and asking the internet for help, shouldn't be.

Comment: Just contact them via their website. If you're writing in English, use the UK website. Give the part numbers. Don't mention that you are in Indonesia. UK call centre here: https://www.se.com/uk/en/work/support/customer-care/contact-schneider-electric.jsp  I'm not really clear what info you want but for example the UK absolutely has different, better electricity standards so if you're wanting just technical info on the product fine, but for installation not necessarily going to be helpful.

Comment: @Mazura I do not mind paying a certified technician for help with my issues as long as they are familiar with the products I am dealing with.

Comment: @FreeMan I do not know whether they have different tiers of support. They could answer all my questions so there was no reason for them to extend my questions to a higher tier support. However, I found that for some answers, they did not provide a comprehensive explanation. For example, when I asked which contactor I should use, they gave me the product code without mentioning that the contactor has two different ratings AC-7a & AC-7b. Not until I bought the two suggested contactors did I understand that I should use the AC-7b rating for inductive loads and they do not meet this rating.

Comment: @thelawnet I tried to ask the UK technical support. When I gave the person the product numbers, he questioned my location and mentioned that those products were not offered in the UK. Some technical agents in other countries even ended the chat the moment they noticed that I was not asking the products they were familiar with.

Comment: I see well maybe if you try some other country you can find where they do sell it.

Comment: "I do not mind paying a certified technician for help with my issues as long as they are familiar with the products I am dealing with" - if this is the case, then maybe you need to give the electricians in your area a call and ask what their familiarity is with your products. Get the most confident one to come out and take a look, and don't be afraid to fire him immediately if his confidence was obviously misplaced/misstated.

Comment: "they gave me the product code without mentioning that the contactor has two different ratings" - sadly, poor communication skills are not limited to the Schneider tech support group. Failure to provide all the necessary details seems rather common (just look at all the questions closed here that "need more details"). When you call them, it sounds like _you_ will have to probe with questions like "are there multiple versions of this?", "Do you have a specific part/model number that I should buy?", "Are there similar versions that might (not) work?", etc.